# vagrant/virtualbox with azure pipelines

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, azure-pipelines

I would like use Vagrant/Virtualbox in Azure Pipelines (the free version for GitHub open-source projects).

When Virtualbox tries to spin up its VM it errors out with

```
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: WHvCapabilityCodeHypervisorPresent is FALSE! Make sure you have enabled the 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' feature. (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
```

which makes me think that nested virtualization isn't turned on.  However, I'm using the `win1803` host, which (I think) is intended for this purpose.  In addition, manually turning on Hyper-V works:

```
> Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result                               
------- -------------- ---------      --------------                               
True    No             Success        {Hyper-V Module for Windows ...
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.  There's lots of examples of running nested VMs (especially using Packer) with Azure DevOps.  Is Azure Pipelines that different?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Pipelines in a part of Azure Devops, so that question doesn't make any sense ;)

Regarding the actual question: if you are using hosted agent - that probably wont work since it doesnt have VT-x enabled, if you are using self-hosted agent you need to use the D\E v3 series vm, they have the VT-x enabled

Comment: The agents available to Azure Pipelines is somewhat limited: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent I'm not sure how to map these onto D\E v3, etc.

Comment: you cannot use d\e v3 for hosted agents. because they are hosted. you get what you get